# $\mathbb{E}[N^2]$ where $N$ is number of dice rolls and each six gives $5$ more

Tags: probability, combinatorics, expected-value, dice

Initially you are allowed to throw a standard die $10$ times. Each time you roll and successfully get a $6$, you are allowed to throw $5$ more times. So for example, if you get a $6$ in throws $3$, $7$, $12$ and get no other six-s, then you throw a total of $10 + 3\cdot 5 = 25$ times. Let $N$ be the total random number of throws. What is the expected value $\mathbb{E}[N^2]$?

It is easy to compute $\mathbb{E}[N]$ as $10(1 + 5p + (5p)^2 + \cdots)$ where $p=1/6$ is the probability for getting a $6$. Can we compute in a similar tricky manner Var$(N)$ perhaps?

Comment: "You are allowed to..." That vaguely gives the impression that you have a choice when to stop. Really, what you have is a starting number $k_0=10$ and if you roll a six, the next roll you have $k_{n+1}=k_n+4$ and otherwise $k_{n+1}=k_n-1.$ You stop when $k_n=0.$

Comment: I am a little confused with the description, as you give the impression that you roll a die 10 times, then count the number of sixes, say $k,$ and then you roll the die another $5k$ times. That's it, no more rolls. So the maximum number of rolls would be $60,$ but you wrote a series, so the description I understood is not the one you meant. Care to correct me?

Comment: @williamM It’s probably like this. There is a counter, initially at ten. Before rolling a die, you must decrease the counter by 1. Each time the roll is six, you increase the counter by 5. You keep rolling until the counter hits zero.

Answer (score 2):

Let $k_n$ be the number of rolls remaining, after $n$ rolls. You end when $k_n=0.$ $k_0=10.$

Then $k_{n+1}=k_n+4$ if the next roll is a six, otherwise $k_{n+1}=k_n-1.$

Then if $N_i$ is the number of rolls to get from $k_n=i+1$ to $k_m=i,$ where $n,m$ are the first occurrences of $i+1,i$ in $k_0,\dots,$ then the $N_i$ are i.i.d.s.

Your $N=N_9+N_8+\cdots+N_0,$ and you get:

$$E(N^2)=10E(N_0^2)+90E(N_0)^2.$$

Now, $E(N_0)=6,$ so the question is, what is $E(N_0^2)?$

Now, $E(N_0^2)=\frac56\cdot1^2+\frac16E\left((1+N_4+N_3+N_2+N_1+N_0)^2\right)$

So $$E(N_0^2)=1+\frac16\left(2\cdot5 E(N_0)+20E(N_0)^2+5E(N_0^2)\right)$$

Again using $E(N_0)=6,$ we get:

$$E(N_0^2)=6+60+720=786.$$

So $$E(N^2)=10\cdot 786+90\cdot 36=11,100.$$

This assume $E(N^2)$ is finite, which might take some proof.

If you replace adding $5$ rolls to adding $6$ or more, you will see $E(N),E(N^2)$ are not finite. So it may require a little work.

---

If $k_0=k,$ and $r$ is the number of rolls added on six, and $p$ is the probability of a six, you get $E(N)=kE(N_0)$ with: $$E(N_0)=1+prE(N_0).$$ or $E(N_0)=\frac{1}{1-pr}.$ Obviously, this doesn't make sense if $pr\geq 1.$

Now, $$E(N^2)=kE(N_0^2)+(k^2-k)\frac1{(1-pr)^2}$$

And:

$$E(N_0^2)=1+p\left(2rE(N_0)+rE(N_0^2)+(r^2-r)E(N_0)^2\right)$$ or $$ E(N_0^2)=\frac{1}{1-pr}+\frac{2pr}{(1-pr)^2}+\frac{p(r^2-r)}{(1-pr)^3}.$$

If $q=\frac1{1-pr}=E(N_0),$ then:

$$E(N_0^2)=q+2prq^2+(r^2-r)pq^3$$

Then $$E(N^2)=kE(N_0^2)+(k^2-k)q^2=kq(1+2rpq+(k-1)q+(r^2-r)pq^2)$$

---

If we can find the moment generating function for $N_0,$ $M_{N_0}(t),$ then we can find the moment generating function $M_{N}(t)=M_{N_0}(t)^k.$ Then we can find all the moments, $E(N^d)=M_{N}^{(d)}(0).$

We have:

$$M_{N_0}(t)=E(e^{N_0t})=(1-p)e^t+pM_{N_0}^r(t).$$

So $\alpha=M_{N_0}(t)$ is a root if $p\alpha^r-\alpha+(1-p)e^t=0.$ It seems likely that there are two real roots, though, so that doesn't fully specify $M_{N_0}.$

Comment: This calculates the expectation of $N$ and not of $N^2$, please read the question again.

Comment: Sorry, now calculating $E(N^2).$